# why does json_decode break when passed specific strings?

Tags: php, base64, json

here is my function in a class called getminecraftprofile.php 
basically it takes data from https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/
dependant on the UUID of the user and gets an array that i can pick formation from.
the URL strings are base64 encoded so it decodes that as well.

```
public function getSkin()
{
$properties = $this->properties;
$encoded = json_encode($properties);
$imgUrl = json_decode(base64_decode(json_decode($encoded,true)[0]['value']),true)    ['textures']['SKIN']['url'];
$img = file_get_contents($imgUrl);
echo($img);
}
```

this is the file that is passing in what user profile to find and get the skin of that profile. for most profiles it works perfectly and you can see it in action at http://jamesplanet.net/test/src/getskin.php?username=dinnerbone

```
<?php
include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/test/src/getminecraftprofile.php' )?>
<?php 
$profile = ProfileUtils::getProfile("useruser3");

//$result = $profile->getSkin();
$properties = $profile->getProperties();
$encoded = json_encode($properties);
$imgUrl = json_decode(base64_decode(json_decode($encoded,true)[0]['value']),true)['textures']['SKIN']['url'];
$img = file_get_contents($imgUrl);
var_dump($encoded);
echo('Texture URL Decoded: ' . $imgUrl );
```

it all grinds to a halt however if i say

```
$profile = ProfileUtils::getProfile("_jeb");
```

then it throws this at me

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in      /Applications/AMPPS/www/test/src/getskin.php on line 10
string(908) "[{"name":"textures","value":"eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE0MDM0ODE0Mjk2NDMsInByb2ZpbGVJZCI6IjdmM2ZjY2ZjYzUzOTQzNTdhZmEwMjExYTYyODc3MWU0IiwicHJvZmlsZU5hbWUiOiJfamViIiwiaXNQdWJsaWMiOnRydWUsInRleHR1cmVzIjp7fX0=","signature":"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"}]" Texture URL Decoded:
```

i know there is data there because its visible before the base64 decode.
where is it going wrong?

here is an example of what is being parsed

```
{"id":"069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5","name":"Notch","properties":[{"name":"textures","value":"eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE0MDM0ODE0MjIwNDUsInByb2ZpbGVJZCI6IjA2OWE3OWY0NDRlOTQ3MjZhNWJlZmNhOTBlMzhhYWY1IiwicHJvZmlsZU5hbWUiOiJOb3RjaCIsImlzUHVibGljIjp0cnVlLCJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvYTExNmU2OWE4NDVlMjI3ZjdjYTFmZGRlOGMzNTdjOGM4MjFlYmQ0YmE2MTkzODJlYTRhMWY4N2Q0YWU5NCJ9LCJDQVBFIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvM2Y2ODhlMGU2OTliM2Q5ZmU0NDhiNWJiNTBhM2EyODhmOWM1ODk3NjJiM2RhZTgzMDg4NDIxMjJkY2I4MSJ9fX0=","signature":"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"}]}
```

Comment: It will be way easier if you provide the string that causes the error. In other news, your `getSkin()` function IS crazy. json_encode -> json_decode -> base64_decode -> json_decode - I am pretty sure you didn't understand the data format you are processing. And last, but not least: The code for `getProfile` is missing.

Comment: the source for the code can be downloaded here http://jamesplanet.net/test/src/

Comment: No, it can't. Best guess: The error you are getting is inside the code of the `getProfile` function you didn't copy into your question.